# Automapper concern - what if I remove property from view, but not viewmodel?

Tags: model-view-controller, viewmodel, automapper

I've just started using AutoMapper in an MVC ASP.NET project to map my domain models to my view models. eg.

```
public class PersonModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string NickName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string NickName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
}

// Somewhere...
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonModel, PersonViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonViewModel, PersonModel>();
```

Having adopted this pattern, I'm concerned the following scenario happening in future:

1) Developer A creates Person View which shows editors for all 4x properties

2) Developer B later removes "Nickname" editor from the Person View, but leaves in PersonViewModel

3) Because the Nickname value is never preserved in the View, hence submitted on Save, Automapper starts mapping a null value for "Nickname" from PersonViewModel -> PersonModel and overwriting data without any run-time or compile-time warning.

Is this a legitimate risk, have you run into it, and how did you deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

You can mitigate against such risks by having server side validation and automated end to end testing.

So in your example one of the tests would be that 'when saving a person the nickname should contain a value'.

Comment: The question is how you can mitigate this risk in a general, global way, without having to code it up manually for each field. If you have to code it up manually field by field, then there is no point using Automapper.

Comment: How would the server side code know that a null value is legitimate or not without server side validation? The scenario you mention would occur with any type of mapping, manual or automated, so it's more a question of having a good test suite rather than a mapping issue.

Comment: There could be a legitimate null value entered.... so null itself is not the problem. The problem is that a dev could easily break the data just by removing a field from the view - with no indication whatsoever other than a bug report 6 months later.